# How would I run cmd commands with Python and take input from them?

Tags: python-3.x, cmd

I would like write some python to run a cmd ping test and let me know if/when I get a general failure. (I know it's really specific don't ask).
What I really want to do is not just run a cmd command from python, but I also want it to use the results as input to display a message when the failure happens with a timestamp.

The idea I had was to take the output from the cmd and check for the string 'fail' within each line, but I'm not sure how to achieve this given the cmd seems hard to read with python with my current knowledge.

Comment: Unfortunately we don't build full solutions for you here. You would need to provide what you are already trying to use to achieve your goal along with any specific issues or errors you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subprocess` module in python and do something like below. Replace the `cmd` variable with your command that you want to execute.

```
import subprocess

cmd = ['ls', '-lrt']

p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
output, err = p.communicate()
print('-' * 50, 'OUTPUT', '-' * 50)
print(output.decode())
print('fail' in err.decode())
```